# $\mathbb R$ with usual metric homeomorphic to open interval $(0,\,1)$

Tags: general-topology

Is $\mathbb R$ with usual metric homeomorphic to interval $(0,\,1)$? If yes please give some hints how to write properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: can you think of an open, continuous (in fact differentiable) bijection $f : \mathbb{R} \to I$ for some open, bounded interval $I$? If so, then all you need to do is compose with the linear function from $I$ to $(0,1)$.

Comment: Why would we need linear map? Can't we directly use (0,1) interval instead of I?

Comment: Yeah you can. I was just hinting at $\arctan(x)$, which is the first bijection from $\mathbb{R}$ to an interval I think of. If you want a direct map, an easy way is to instead map from $(0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ by taking $\tan(x)$ and scaling.

Comment: Ok thanks I got your point :)